# summarizing option enumerate in a command

Tags: macros, enumerate, enumitem

How summarize option enumerate in a command. like this

```
\newcommand{\enumseting}{leftmargin=.7cm,itemindent=0cm,labelwidth=0cm,labelsep=.2cm,align=right}‎
```

Comment: Please post working examples, not just fragments of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use clone lists of a enumerate and `\setlist` to specifiy the settings for this.

Another one is `\SetEnumitemKey`, e.g.

```
\SetEnumitemKey{mykeys}{leftmargin=.7cm,itemindent=0cm,labelwidth=0cm,labelsep=.2cm,align=right}
```

The name `mykeys` is arbitrary (basically).

In this example, both lists show the same output.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\newlist{enumclone}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumclone]{leftmargin=.7cm,itemindent=0cm,labelwidth=0cm,labelsep=.2cm,align=right,label={\arabic*.}}

\SetEnumitemKey{mykeys}{leftmargin=.7cm,itemindent=0cm,labelwidth=0cm,labelsep=.2cm,align=right}



\begin{document}

\begin{enumclone}
  \item First
  \item Second
\end{enumclone}


\begin{enumerate}[mykeys]
  \item First
  \item Second
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

For more fine control there is the command

```
\SetEnumitemValue{key}{string value}{replacement}
```

which allows to 'rename' existing key values, here `\begin{enumerate}[label=numeric]` for example.